# Copy or export text from Outlook mails that appear in search results

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I want to post-process the text of multiple mails that appear in my Outlook search results. Ideally I would be able to copy & paste the mails appearing in the search results into an Excel workbook or a simple text or CSV file.

**What I have tried until now:** When having the list of desired mails in the results pane, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all mails. Then I copy via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then I paste via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> into an Excel workbook. However, this only pastes the fields `From`, `Subject`, `Received`, `Size`, and `Categories`. I would also need the content of the mail.

**Hence my question is:** Is it possible to get the content of mails appearing in Outlook search results in a processable manner (e.g., Excel workbook, CSV file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook doesn't provide any builtin functions for that. So, you'll either need to write a VBA macro or use the third-party tool (I can recommend one if you need).